# Setting individual indices of a char array equal to ints

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int any(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    //converts to lower case
    int c = 'a';
    int i1 = 0;
    while (s1[i1] != '\0') {
        if (s1[i1] >= 'A' && s1[i1] <= 'Z')
            s1[i1] += 32;
        ++i1;
    }
    int i2 = 0;
    while (s2[i2] != '\0') {
        if (s2[i2] >= 'A' && s2[i2] <= 'Z')
            s2[i2] += 32;
        ++i2;
    }
    i1 = 0;
    while (s1[i1] != '\0') {
        i2 = 0;
        while (s2[i2] != '\0') {
            if (s1[i1] == s2[i2])
                return i1;
            ++i2;
        }
        ++i1;
    }
    return -1;
}

main() {
    //printf("test");
    printf("%d", any("This is fun", "fin"));
}
```

This code causes a segmentation fault and I'm pretty sure it happens when I try to set one of the chars in the array equal to an int.  How do I not get a seg fault?

Comment: @chqrlie: yes, indentation is a good idea, but there's no rule you have to put a space after keywords (and binary operators can go either way).

Comment: @chqrlie: I understand your point, but my point is that you should not be forcing your opinions on others like this.  Instructing someone to put spaces after keywords (as if they have done something wrong) is poor form, just like instructing someone to spell "color" after they spelled it "colour".  (Also, the inventor of C is dead now, and AFAIK was not involved in go.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: my bad, Brian Kernighan did not invent C, he merely co-authored *The C Programming Language*, and so did *The Go Programming Language*. RIP Dennis Ritchie.  I agree that I was a bit strong in my initial remark, but the code was badly presented, as so many posts on SO, and the first step to finding the bugs is a good run through `cb`.

Comment: @DanielBurgess: sorry for my harsh remark on your coding style. C does not impose any style for the source code, but experience shows that a consistent indentation of 4 spaces and a fair amount of spaces to make binary operators, keywords, braces, function arguments, variable declarations stand out helps readability a lot and makes bugs more visible.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `any` with pointers to string constants.  Attempting to modify these strings invokes undefined behavior.

Also note that the prototype for `main` should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, and `main` should return `0` for successful operation.

You are implementing a case insensitive version of a generalized version of `strchr` with multiple characters, but you should not modify the argument strings, and you should rely on the functions from `<ctype.h>` instead of assuming ASCII.

Here is a better version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int any(const char s1[], const char s2[]) {
    int i1 = 0;
    while (s1[i1] != '\0') {
        int i2 = 0;
        while (s2[i2] != '\0') {
            if (tolower((unsigned char)s1[i1]) == tolower((unsigned char)s2[i2]))
                return i1;
            ++i2;
        }
        ++i1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    //printf("test");
    printf("%d", any("This is fun", "fin"));
    return 0;
}
```